# Is trunk required in SVN if developing in branches

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

I'm currently thinking about strategies for managing source code in SVN and am wondering if *trunk* is really needed if we are developing code in branches and then tagging the final version.

As an example imagine that we have released version one of our application and so there is a tagged folder **tags/1.0.0** which contains the source code.

The company wants us to immediately start work on version 2 of the application and so we branch off from the **tags/1.0.0** folder creating a new folder, for example: **branches/2.0.0-working**.

Work can continue in this folder until development is completed.  In the meantime if any fixes or small enhancements are required to the 1.0 release then these can again be branched off from the tag, for example: **branches/1.1.0-working** and tagged once they are complete.

If these additional 1.x versions are also required for the version 2.0 release then they can be merged forward to the **branches/2.0.0-working** folder before release.

In this case (so long as the above is technically possible) I'm not sure whether a *trunk* folder would be useful?  Additionally it seems as though it would be much easier to identify where to start development using this strategy rather than using trunk.  For example if after the above a bug was found with version 1.1 we could create another branch **branches/1.2.0-working** from the **tags/1.1.0** release and just get to work.  If there were something in trunk at this point it would be hard to know which version this reflected.

Am I missing something? :)

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something? :)

No, you have it correct.  What you describe is essentially the system we use at my company, and it works fine.  svn itself doesn't care whether you use trunk or not, and we switched over from using trunk to using only branches for exactly the reason you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The terms `trunk`, `tags`, and `branches` are merely defaults for you to use.

The `trunk` is usually used for continuous development, and branching is used to allow for dual development streams.

For example, you work off of `trunk` for version 1.0 of your software. When you get to the point where version 1.0 is about to be released, and some people want to start working on the post-1.0 version (we'll call it version 2.0), you branch 1.0 off of trunk. Those working on 2.0 will work on the trunk. Those working on the `1.0` release work on the branch. When 1.0 is complete, you tag off the `1.0` branch, and those developers continue working on `trunk` for that `2.0` release. Any changes on the `1.0` branch that are needed for trunk can be merged (via cherry picking) from `1.0` to `trunk`.

If a bug is found in version 1.0, and you want a version `1.1`, you simply continue working off the `1.0` branch, and tag that revision.

What you're doing is simply making each branch a trunk. The only issue I see is what happens when `1.0.0` gets to the point where you want a *code freeze* (no new features, but bug fixes), and you don't need all of your developers working on that release. In your scenario, they simply wait until 1.0.0 is released before they continue work.

If you have 50 developers and only 5 are needed to finish up a release, this isn't necessarily a good use of the other 45. However, in small shops, you don't have this issue. Most of the time, everyone is working on the same development stream at the same time. In that case, why bother with branches? No, really. This is not a snarky comment.

I've worked with small shops, and we didn't have branching. Everyone pretty much worked on trunk, and there was no need for branching at all. We tagged right off of trunk, and then continue working. No need for a new branch at all. If we needed a hotfix in a release, we branch off the tag as you do, do the fix, and then tag off the hotfix branch.

For your practice, as long as you follow your workflow, and make sure all work on that 1.0.0 branch is done first before you do that 2.0.0 branch, you should be fine. The problems happen when you branch that 2.0.0 branch while still working on that 1.0.0 branch. In that case, you have to make sure that all the 1.0.0 work not on that 2.0.0 branch is merged back in.

Branching is like having kids. If you create one, you have to remember to do the upkeep. If you don't have to branch, why bother? This way, you can sleep through the night without some branching issue keeping you up at 2:00am.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is fine, but going without a trunk does have a few minor drawbacks.

- You have to make more "working" branches.  With a trunk you only need to create working branches for revisions to previous releases; "version next" does not require its own working folder because its work is being done in the trunk.
- You make developers working on the latest and greatest do an "svn switch" after every release instead of staying on the trunk, which some might consider a minor annoyance.
- You're following a different convention than what is most commonly done.  That's not always bad, but it is a consideration (which you already know or you wouldn't have asked the question).

I'm also not sure you're gaining anything.  With or without a trunk, revising a previous release starts by copying the release's tag folder into a working branch, just as you do today.  The history in each folder, whether tag, branch, or newest development, will be 100% identical using either method.  Neither approach is more or less confusing about what went into a release, or where you ought to be writing a particular chunk of code.

It makes sense to follow conventions that are similar to what others do, but if you don't find a piece of the convention helpful, fine, do what provides value.  I'm not convinced going without a trunk provides value, but if you and your team do, then pick a repository layout that works for you.